# $_POST To PHP Page

Tags: php, variables

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Firstly apologies as I am new to this, so to some this may seem a very basic error.

I'm using the form below to allow users to navigate between different pages all based around a 'Location' record.

```
<form name="locations" id="locations" method="post" action="locationsaction.php">

    <?php

        <table width="538" border="0">
        <tr>
        <th width="119"><div align="left">Location Name</div></th>
        <th width="159"><div align="left">Address</div></th>
        <th width="94"><div align="center">No. Of Finds</div></th>
        <th width="69"></th>
        <th width="66"></th>
        <th width="5"></th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><div align="left"><?php echo $lid;?></div></td>
        <td><div align="left"><?php echo $lname;?></div></td>
        <td><div align="left"><?php echo $laddress;?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo $findscount?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value="View Details"/></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value="Add Finds"/></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value=" Add Images"/></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><th colspan="8"><br/><hr width="100%"></th></tr>
        </table>
        <?php
</form>
```

At the end of the form you will notice that there are three 'Submit' buttons which takes the user to different pages. The following PHP script is used to determine which button has been selected and is shown in the above `Form POST`action as `locationsaction.php`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $urls = array(
        'View Details' => 'updatelocation.php',
        'Add Finds' => 'addfinds.php',
        'Add Images' => 'image.php'
    );
    $url = $urls[$_POST['type']];
    header("Location: " . $url);
}
?>
```

Although the buttons work fine, as in they take the user to the correct page, I cannot get the `$lid` variable to be passed to any of the three receiving pages and I receive the following error: 
`Notice: Undefined index: lid in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/updatelocation.php`

This is how I'm trying to get the `$lid` variable in all my receiving pages:

```
$lid = $_POST['lid'];
```

I've looked through several tutorials and posts on this site, and I can't find out where I'm going wrong.

I just wondered whether someone could have a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Why submit and redirect when you could put the links right in the page?  You aren't actually submitting any data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put the $lid variable in an input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lid" value="<?=$lid?>" />
```

Otherwise it won't be posted in the form.

Also, when you redirect, the POST variables won't be redirected with you. You can either append them to the url (http://url.tld?lid=value), and then get at them like so:

```
$lid = $_GET['lid'];
```

However, a better way might be to save them in a session:

```
$_SESSION['lid'] = $_POST['lid'];
// Redirect here
```

Then on the next page, you can access them:

```
$lid = $_SESSION['lid'];
```

Comment: Hi @Toddish thank you for taking the time to look at my post, but more importantly for taking the time to help me. It works great. Many thanks. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the `lid` value through POST to any of the scripts. If you want to pass it, put something like this in your form:

```
<input type = "hidden" value = "<?= $lid ?>" name = "lid" />
```

Comment: Hi @robbrit, thank you very much for helping me out with this. It's truly appreciated. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

**Everything** you want to post has to be in an `input` (or `select` or `textarea`) and have a name.

That is **not** so in your form.

Comment: Hi @Neal I just want to say thank you for taking the time to look at my post, but more importantly for taking the time to help me. It is truly, greatly appreciated. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM no problem, ^_^ anytime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a form element containing the `$lid` variable.  Something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lid" value="<?php echo $lid; ?>" />
```

Comment: Hi @curtisdf, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I've got this working perfectly now. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

your $lid variable is sent through to locationsaction.php but not to updatelocation.php,

to go around this, you could define $_SESSION['lid'] = $lid;  in the locationsaction.php

Comment: Hi @Wampie Driessen, thank you very much for this. Along with the other guidance I've received, I've got this working perfectly. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so schematically here is your architecture:

> form > locationsaction.php > updatelocation.php (or another one,
>   depends on the button)

You have access to POST into locationsaction.php because you actually posted datas, using the submit buttons of your form. But now if you need datas in `updatelocation.php`, you can't use `$_POST` to retrieve it unless you POST datas again.

Instead, I recommend you use `$_SESSION` array to store values and use them through your different php pages.

Comment: Hi @Sebas, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I've got this working perfectly now. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The inputs elements are mandatories (hidden etc..) for pass value with form.
If the locationaction.php isn't so really impotant to use, i suggest you to change directly action fom into the first page.

```
<td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" onclick="window.locations.action='updatelocation.php'" value="View Details"/></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input name="type" onclick="window.locations.action='addfind.php'" type="submit" value="Add Finds"/></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" onclick="window.locations.action='image.php'" value=" Add Images"/></div></td>
        </tr>
```

However, when you use an intermediate page to retrives and sends post values you can use this code

```
<form name="iaminthemiddle" action="finaldest.php" method="post">
<?php
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
 echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$k\" value=\"$v\">";
?>
</form>
<script>window.iaminthemiddle.submit();</script>
```

This for $_POST elements, you can retrive also the querystring values with $_GET or both with $_REQUEST

Comment: Hi @Goonie, thank you for this. I've managed to get everything working for the moment using the other method. However I'll set up some test pages so I can try this. Kind regards